# iOS Photos App tabbar icons how to get that icons from system

Tags: ios, swift, icons, swift4, photo

I am making a tutorial video on the photos app of ios. I want to clone that app. I need icons that Photos tabs have. from where and how can I get these icons if available ib system icons

I searched all in google but I unable  to get these icons

[image]

Comment: you can create yourself , or just go on flat icons

Comment: http://www.iconbeast.com/free/

Comment: you can find this icon on the second row at second last postion

Comment: @ Taimoor Suleman thanks bro but this are little different

Answer (score 0):

I have created these icons with previewer app in MAC posted here just to motivate and help the guy

[icons 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rHEH.png)

[Icon 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GczCg.png)

[Icon 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pshDw.png)

For Search Icon you can find it from anywhere like flat icons or any other site

Comment: Thanks, bro may you live long

Comment: Thanks ;) if that helped can you please click on tick mark so that another persons get help via this ?

Comment: if icons not shown well on tabbar try by reducing icons size :)

Comment: bro done thanks for your help, can u please upvote my question someone has done negative vote

Comment: i have up voted your answer, but take care next time stack overflow is a code based  site you can't post things about graphics over here  use ask Different  for this or on meta exchange